# Change only method result and class loader NoSuchMethod

Tags: java, classloader, name-mangling

We started with one jar with one class with one method like:

```
boolean foo( int bar ) { ... }
```

However, the result of this method was useless (in fact, always true) and clients that used this result for anything fails in an error. For this reason, method was changed to:

```
void foo( int bar ) { ... }
```

and all items recompiled. Thus, we can assume all users of this jar calls the method as:

```
foo(14);
```

none uses the form (and is out of scope for this question if there are someone):

```
boolean x = foo(14);
```

**Assume none client, new or older, uses the boolean result.**

The problem was when, **in target systems**, the new jar is loaded without upgrading the clients. Not updated clients fails with an exception "NoSuchMethod" when looking for the "foo" method with result "boolean". That is:

- client has an statment like "foo(14);" without usage of the method result
- client is compiled using the jar with boolean method.
- client and library is loaded in target system
- library is updated with new jar with void method
- client crashes with "NoSuchMethod"

The origin of the problem seems to be that both, Java and C/C++ doesn't allows two methods that differs only in result, but only Java "name mangling" includes the result type in the name that class loader (linker in C/C++) is looking for.

The question is: it is possible to trick in any way the library jar or the class loader to skip  "NoSuchMethod" exception in this scenario?

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is fully expected. This is because client's compiled classes contain [*constant pool*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4), which includes *symbolic reference* to a method.

Let's suppose we have class `FooClass` with two methods:

```
public boolean foo1(int bar) {
    return true;
}

public void foo2(int bar) {
    // ...
}
```

And let's suppose we have another class `Main` where we invoke both methods:

```
    FooClass fc = new FooClass();
    fc.foo1(1);
    fc.foo2(1);
```

If we will disassemble `Main.class` we will see that method references differ not only in their names, but in returned type (notice **(I)Z** and **(I)V**):

```
     7: astore_1
     8: aload_1
     9: iconst_1
    10: invokevirtual #4                  // Method q42340444/FooClass.foo1:(I)Z
    13: pop
    14: aload_1
    15: iconst_1
    16: invokevirtual #5                  // Method q42340444/FooClass.foo2:(I)V
```

Where constant pool contains:

```
   #4 = Methodref          #2.#25         // q42340444/FooClass.foo1:(I)Z
   #5 = Methodref          #2.#26         // q42340444/FooClass.foo2:(I)V
```

In other words, it preserves original method's return type and looks in linked libraries for exactly same method, which causes `NoSuchMethod` exception in your case.

More specifically, compiled user classes are linked to `FooClass.foo:(I)Z` method, while your new library doesn't contain method with such description, but only `FooClass.foo:(I)V`.

**Conclusion**: You can not solve this problem without keeping old method signature (may be it is better annotate that method with `@Deprecated` annotation), or by recompiling client's code.

Comment: Yes, it is as you describe, but your the suggestion to solve current real problem is ?

Comment: You can not solve it without keeping old method signature or recompiling client's code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not "keep" older method and newer one, because Java doesn't allows two methods that differs only in result type.

Comment: Rename it to `foo2(int bar)` :) There is no other way

Comment: What about a custom class loader with @Override of "findClass"?

Comment: :) You can, but this will involve client's code changes as well. You can not just substitute classloader from 3d-party-library

Comment: Is it possible a class loader custom for a single jar or class in a jar?

Comment: You can not do that without modifying client's code.

Comment: Or, you can try write custom wrapper, which will load both: client's and you jar with custom classloader.

Comment: But I'm not sure that such trick with custom class loader will work. It is hard to say without trying life code. I have doubts about this decision, and I feel that you will have to create somekind of "fake" or "synthetic" method.

Answer (score 1):

Just my thoughts.

You can try to modify a class's bytecode after actual compilation using [special tools](https://java-source.net/open-source/bytecode-libraries) as a hotfix. In bytecode such methods can coexist.